# Convert escaped unicode character in string to character

Tags: elisp

How can I convert a string containing an escaped unicode character to a character?

`(string-to-char "\\u03C0")` evaluates to `92` which is the character value of the first `\` in the string.  I somehow need to modify the string so I can call `(string-to-char "\u03C0")` and get `960`.  `(substring "\\u03C0" 1)` evaluates to `"u03c0"` which isn't quite right either!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the part after `\u` with `substring`, and convert it to a number using base 16:

```
ELISP> (string-to-number (substring "\\u03C0" 2) 16)
960 (#o1700, #x3c0, ?π)
```

Answer (score 2):

14 characters shorter than legoscia's suggestion :)

```
(read (format "?%s" "\\u03C0"))
```

Comment: `(read (format "?%s" "\\u03C0"))` actually seems to be enough!

Comment: Oh, yes, numbers are self-evaluating, so no need to eval it :)