# Function to replace strings from region and save result in kill-ring

Tags: replace, query-replace-regexp

I'm almost completely ignorant in elisp, but I'd like to have a function that does the following:

1. Takes a string from (a) a region, if one is selected, or (b) user prompt, if a region is not selected.
2. Internally replaces a couple of regexp in the string with other strings. (Specifically, first "[^a-zA-Z_- ]" with "", and then "[_ ]+" with "_").
3. Saves the new string obtained from the replacement into the kill-ring or the clipboard.

Note that the original region is *not* changed.

My starting point was the piece of elisp below, taken from snips I've seen, to take care of 1.. Please note that I barely understand what this code actually does:

```
defun changestring (&optional arg)
  "Replace some character in string and save to kill-ring."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (use-region-p)
      (let ((region (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end))))
*** the replacing part should go here ***
    )
    (let ((region (read-string "String to be converted: ")))
*** the replacing part should go here, again ***
      )
    )
  )
```

I've been told that it can be slimmed down – indeed it looks like the replacement part is done twice.

Stackexchange seems to have some answers about saving to kill-ring, e.g. [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/51861/20754) and [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/63725/20754), and modifying strings internally, e.g. [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/10261/20754) and [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/63155/20754), but I really don't understand how to modify the code in those answers to this particular problem.

I wonder if anyone can help me, at least with all parts besides the regexp part, which I think I can modify myself. Of course a comment of your code is also greatly appreciated, so I can learn some elisp. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One implementation might be this:

```
(defun changestring (&optional arg)
  "Replace some character in string and save to kill-ring."
  (interactive "p")
  ;; conditionally let variables and only execute the body if all of them are evaluated to non-nil
  ;; `str' is not an empty string
  ;; `regex1' and regex2 are not nil (obviously they wouldn't, they just strings)
  ;; `repl-str' is not nil after all the replacements
  (when-let* ((str (if (use-region-p)
                       (buffer-substring-no-properties (region-beginning) (region-end))
                     (read-string "String to be converted: ")))
              (regex1 "[_ ]")
              (regex2 "[^a-zA-Z_-]")
              ;; thread-last is like clojure's ->> threading macro, simply
              ;; speaking, it passes first argument to the last argument of the
              ;; following functions. `str' would be passed to
              ;; (replace-regexp-in-string regex1 "_" str) then result of that
              ;; function call would be passed to the next
              ;; replace-regexp-in-string.
              ;; this is equivalent to
              ;; (replace-regexp-in-string regex2 "" (replace-regexp-in-string regex1 "_" str))
              (repl-str (thread-last str
                                     (replace-regexp-in-string regex1 "_")
                                     (replace-regexp-in-string regex2 ""))))
    ;; create temp buffer, insert repl-str there and save whole temp buffer into clipboard
    (with-temp-buffer
      (insert repl-str)
      (clipboard-kill-ring-save (point-min) (point-max)))))
```

Regexes are a bit different to yours and the order is different too -- otherwise first regex removes all spaces and the second one doesn't make sense (there are no spaces and underlines to replace after the first replace).

PS

[image: asciicast]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you so much! Your comment makes sense, there's a little space in the brackets of the first regexp, I just fixed that. The rest of the script would have been quite difficult for me :)

Comment: PS: very interesting the `with-temp-buffer`, never thought of something like that. Thank you for the explanation there and in the rest of the code.

Comment: Sure, happy lisping!